# Passport authentication worked (somewhat), need to get user object

Tags: node.js, passport.js, openid-connect, saml

I have the code below and it seems to work. I'm able to redirect to the OIDC login page if needed, and it goes back to the callback that I'm expecting. I cannot get the request.isAuthenticated() to work, so I had to fall back to checking for the presence of both the grant_id to determine if the user is authenticated. However, I need to know basic things about the user, ie. their name, email, etc. I'm expecting this to come from the req.user object, but passport didn't define that either. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong with this?

```
/**
 * How the application respond to clients requests depending of the endpoint
 */
const userController = require('../controllers/userController');
var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-ci-oidc').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
const strategyConfiguration = require('../../config/strategy.json');
console.log('strategyConfiguration=' + JSON.stringify(strategyConfiguration));
const passport = require('passport');
const https = require('https');
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function (app) {

  console.log('App setting title=' + app.get('title'));
  console.log('App env=' + app.get('env'));

  console.log('App setting query parser=' + app.get('query parser'));
  console.log('App setting string routing=' + app.get('strict routing'));
  console.log('App setting case sensitive routing=' + app.get('case sensitive routing'));


  var http = require('http');

  var url = require('url');

  var currentOriginalUrl;

  passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
  });

  passport.deserializeUser(function (obj, done) {
    done(null, obj);
  });

  // openid-client is an implementation of the OpenID Relying Party (RP, Client) server
  // for the runtime of Node.js, support passport

  //OAuth 2.0 protocol
  //middleware Passport-OpenID Connect
  const config = require('../configuration/config').getConfiguration();
  console.log('config=' + JSON.stringify(config));
  console.log('strategyConfiguration=' + JSON.stringify(strategyConfiguration));

  var OpenIDConnectStrategy = require('passport-ci-oidc').IDaaSOIDCStrategy;
  var Strategy = new OpenIDConnectStrategy({
    discoveryURL: strategyConfiguration.discoveryURL,
    clientID: strategyConfiguration.clientID,
    scope: 'openid',
    response_type: 'code',
    clientSecret: strategyConfiguration.clientSecret,
    callbackURL: strategyConfiguration.callbackURL,
    skipUserProfile: true, /* this was true before */
    CACertPathList: [
      `/certs/DigiCertGlobalRootCA.crt`,
      `/certs/DigiCertSHA2SecureServerCA.crt`,
    ]
  },
    function (iss, sub, profile, accessToken, refreshToken, params, done) {
      process.nextTick(function () {
        profile.accessToken = accessToken;
        profile.refreshToken = refreshToken;

        const userDetails = profile._json;
        const userProfile = {
          uid: userDetails.uid,
          mail: profile.id,
          cn: decodeURIComponent(userDetails.cn),
          exp: 60 * 60   /*TODO: Get proper number of seconds. userDetails.exp */,
          blueGroups: userDetails.blueGroups,
        };
        done(null, userProfile);

      })
    }
  )

  var proxy_server = require('http-proxy').createProxyServer({});

  const originalUrl = new URL(config.host);
  console.log('matched cost-recovery using original url: ' + originalUrl);
  const newUrl = new URL(originalUrl);
  newUrl.port = 8447;
  console.log('matched cost-recovery new url' + newUrl);


  function saveUrlInSession(request, response, next) {
    if (request.params.state) {
      console.log('Saving state=' + request.params.state + " in session");
      request.session.savedUrl = request.request.params.state;
    } else {
      console.log('Saving originalUrl=' + request.originalUrl + " in session");
      request.session.savedUrl = request.originalUrl;
    }
    if (next) {
      return next();
    } else {
      console.log('@@ no next');
    }
  }

  function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log('@@ ensureAuthenticated reached. Not authenticated. redirecting to /login');
      res.redirect('/login')
    } else {
      console.log('@@ ensureAuthenticated reached. Authenticated. Continuing to next handler');
      return next();
    }
  }

  function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
      console.log('@@isLoggedIn req.isAuthenticated()=true');
      req.session.isAuthenticated = true;
      res.locals.isAuthenticated = true;
      res.locals.user = req.user;
      next(); //If you are authenticated, run the next
    } else {
      console.log('@@isLoggedIn req.isAuthenticated()=false');
      return res.redirect("/login");
    }
  }

  function getUserProfile(req, res, next) {
    console.log('@@ reached getUserProfile')
    if (typeof req.user == 'undefined') {
      res.status(401);
      next();
    }
    return res.status(200).send(req.user);
  }

  function getUserName(req, res, next) {
    console.log('@@ reached getUserName')
    if (typeof req.user === 'undefined') {
      res.status(401);
      return next();
    }
    return res.status(200).send(req.user.cn);
  }

  var newURL = url.format({
    protocol: config.protocol,
    host: config.host,
    pathname: config.originalUrl
  });

  console.log('newURL=' + newURL);
  var newURL2 = new URL(newURL);
  newURL2.port = "8447";
  newURL2.protocol = "http";
  console.log('newURL2=' + newURL2);
  const sprint_cost_recovery_options = {
    target: newURL2,
    level: 'debug',
    changeOrigin: true,
    ws: true
  }
  console.log('@@ sprint_cost_recovery_options=' + JSON.stringify(sprint_cost_recovery_options));

  passport.use(Strategy);

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  app.use(passport.session());
  app.use(function (request, response, next) {
    console.log('Common Route: Incoming request originalUrl:' + request.originalUrl);
    console.log('Common Route: Incoming request previous Url:' + request.header('referer'));
    console.log('Common Route: Incoming request url:' + request.url);
    next();
  });


  app.get('/auth/sso/callback/:callback_uri?'
    , function (request, response, next) {
      console.log('CB-1 matched on originalUrl=' + request.originalUrl);
      console.log('@@ CB-2. isAuthenticated=' + request.isAuthenticated());
      console.log('@@ CB-2.5 request.account test=' + request.account);
      console.log('@@ savedUrl in session=' + request.session.savedUrl);
      //var redirectUrl = poppedUrlFromSession(request);
      var redirectUrl = request.session.savedUrl;
      if (!redirectUrl) {
        redirectUrl = "/health-check";
      }
      console.log('@@ CB-3. redirectUrl=' + redirectUrl);
      console.log('@@ CB-4. before passport.authenticate');
      console.log('@@ CB-5. after passport.authenticate');
      console.log('@@ CB-6. isAuthenticated=' + request.isAuthenticated());
      console.log('@@ auth-sso-callback-2 bp1');
      response.redirect(redirectUrl);

    }
  );

  app.use('/login?:state?',
    function (request, response, next) {
      var stateIndicator = (request.params.state) ? " with state " + request.params.state : " with no state/redirect.";
      console.log('@@ Reached login with ' + stateIndicator);
      return next();
    },
    passport.authenticate('openidconnect', { state: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 10) }));

  app.use('/rules/username', saveUrlInSession, ensureAuthenticated, userController.getUserName);

  app.use('/rules/profile', saveUrlInSession, ensureAuthenticated, userController.getUserProfile);

  app.use('/cost-recovery*', saveUrlInSession, /*ensureAuthenticated*/ isLoggedIn,createProxyMiddleware(sprint_cost_recovery_options));

  app.use('/profile', saveUrlInSession, ensureAuthenticated, getUserProfile);

  app.use('/username', saveUrlInSession, ensureAuthenticated, getUserName);

  app.get('/successful-login', function (req, res) {
    res.send('login succeeded');
  });

  app.get('/failure', function (req, res) {
    res.send('login failed');
  });

  app.get('/health-check', (request, response) => {
    response.send('Middleware is running.');
  });

};
```

Update:
On a separate scaled down project, I was able to get the user id info back. I added this extra call to passport.authenticate with a profile argument and it happens before a protected middleware-handler gets invoked:

```
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
        passport.authenticate('openidconnect', function (err, user, profile) {
                if (err) { return next(err) }
                if (!user) {
                        req.session.originalUrl = req.originalUrl;
                        return res.redirect('/login')
                }
                console.log('@@ logged in. profile='+JSON.stringify(profile));
                return next();
        })(req, res, next);

}
```

I didn't mark this as complete because profile only returned a valid value one time, but it does set the req.user. Unfortunately, the same call does *not* work on my code.

I just want to check is the user authorized, and who are they. It should *not* be *this* hard.